Write two dictionaries into excel rows
I have 2 dictionaries.I want to combine the datas from each dictionary and write into an excel table.
Dictionary A contains PO numbers (Key) and Customer Name (value)
Dictionary B contains PO numbers (Key) and Sku number (Sub key) and quantity (value).
For Dictionary B, sometimes, there could be more than one Sku numbers/quantity from each PO.
DictionaryA = { {PO_1111: John Doe}, {PO_2222: Jane Doe} } 

DictionaryB = { PO_1111: { {sku_A: 1} }, PO_2222: {{sku_A: 1}, {sku_B: 3} } 



Best course of action would be to use the pandas library.

Another course of action is to make a coding attempt and post the code when you get stuck.  SO isn't a coding service so show what you have tried.  Also, your dictionaries are not valid Python syntax.  Make sure you post valid code.

Please replace that image with a code block or table

You will need to write your dictionaries as per the correct syntax and then 'outer merge' the DataFrames. You can then write the output to excel.
import pandas as pd

#Write your dictionaries
DictionaryA = { 
    'PO Number': ['PO_1111', 'PO_2222'],
    'Name': ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
     } 

DictionaryB = { 
    'PO Number': ['PO_1111', 'PO_2222', 'PO_2222'],
    'sku': ['sku_A', 'sku_A', 'sku_B'],
    'Qty': [1 , 1, 3]
    } 

#Convert dictionaries to DataFrames
tableA = pd.DataFrame(DictionaryA)
tableB = pd.DataFrame(DictionaryB)

#Outer merge the DataFrames
ds = tableA.merge(tableB, how='outer', on='PO Number')

#Output to excel
ds.to_excel('output.xlsx')



thank you Adeva. Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction. Now I have an idea of how to solve my problem.
